# Unable to find Remote Desktop icon in System->Preferences

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for around 8 months, but I have a question that probably a "newbie" should be asking.  I'm unable to find the "remote desktop" icon that is generally accessible from Systems-> Preferences. The following [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/configure-remote-access-to-your-ubuntu-desktop) mentions the "remote desktop" icon. (I know the link talks about ubuntu 7.1, but the feature should be there in Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

I need the remote desktop feature to enable others (in other networks) to view my desktop.

Any help would be welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Shantanu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 12.04 it's called 'Desktop Sharing' if you're searching for it from the Ubuntu dash, or you can access the same setup dialog from a terminal by typing `vino-preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop sharing command line tool is called:

vino-preferences

Just another suggestion, There is a command line tool also called > Open a Terminal and type:

rdesktop-vrdp

If you need to install it type: sudo apt-get install -y rdesktop-vrdp